# I can't connect to my docker monogodb from my nodejs using mongoose

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I created an Image of mongodb and mongo-express and mongo-express was able to connect to mongodb

but I am trying to connect to mongodb from nodejs but I am getting error

```
MongoServerError: Authentication failed.
    at Connection.onMessage (/home/oshabz/Desktop/booking app/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:210:30)
    at MessageStream.<anonymous> (/home/oshabz/Desktop/booking app/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:63:60)
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3'
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=admin
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=password
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
```

Mongoose connection String

```
MONGO="mongodb://admin:password@localhost:27017/test_db"
```

I am using mongoose and if I remove test_db from the connection url it connects to mongodb but not to any database.

How do I specify my database if I remove it from the url?

Comment: See also [How to connect to mongodb using docker-compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43162897)

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the **mongodb** container by the DNS name `mongodb` from within the **mongo-express** (client) container.  Docker automatically resolves the name to the container with [a little bit of magic](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/).

Then you can use `mongodb` instead of `localhost` in the connection string.

Within the **mongo-express** container, `localhost` refers to itself, *not* the **mongodb** container, and *not* the host.

Change:

```
MONGO="mongodb://admin:password@localhost:27017/test_db"
```

to:

```
MONGO="mongodb://admin:password@mongodb:27017/test_db"
```

Comment: I changed it but it did not work. I am getting error MongooseServerSelectionError: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN mongodb